# How to block TV from accessing WAN through DD-WRT router

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

Can anyone tell me how I can block a TV that's on my wifi from accessing anything outside the LAN?

I do want the TV to be able to access local PCs however, so I can use its inbuilt apps to play videos from a local DLNA server on my HTPC.

But I don't want it to be able to access its firmware server, ad servers, or anything else outside my house.

My router is a TP-Link TL-WDR3600 v1 running DD-WRT v3.0-r46788 std.

Answer (score 0):

[image: DD-WRT Access Policy Screen]

I found it, it's in "Access Restrictions"-"WAN Access".

I chose Status: Enable, and Deny after entering the MAC of the TV into the list of clients.

That should always block it from accessing WAN.

Answer (score 0):

In the Administration tab, go to the Commands sub-tab. Type `ifconfig` into the commands text box, then click "Run Commands". Search through the output for your WAN IP as shown in the top-right of the page. Verify the interface with that IP address is "vlan2" (interface names are the left column). If it is not, you'll need to replace "vlan2" with the name of the interface bearing that address.

Now, paste the following into the "commands" text box, then alter it to match your needs:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -o vlan2 -j DROP
```

... replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with the tv's LAN IP address